# Sorting MySQL table by deadline

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a MySQL table with projects and I want to sort it by deadline.
So I have something like `SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY deadline`. But the problem is that the deadline column is optional and the value can be NULL. I want the table to be sorted ascendingly, but the NULL deadlines to go at the bottom of the results. They currently appear on the top because of the ascending order. Can I do that in a purely MySQL way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sort by the result of the condition `deadline is null`. It is either `1` or `0`. Then by the `deadline` itself

```
SELECT * FROM projects 
ORDER BY deadline is null, 
         deadline
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,it should work

```
 SELECT * FROM projects   
 ORDER BY IF(deadline = '' or deadline is null,1,0),deadline ASC
```

Comment: That won't put the rows with a null value at the bottom.